# ASCII characters in an image steganography

Tags: steganography

Given an image size of 300 by 400, what is the maximum number of ASCII characters (7 bits) that can be embedded using the LSB steganography?

I would assume that every pixel can perform an LSB so would that mean 300x400 bits change? I should then divide this by 7?

I'm confused about how this works. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Each pixel could also contain 3-4 bits (one per colour / alpha channel)

Comment: I thought one pixel is on binary of 1's and 0's to create a colour. So would that mean 8 bits per pixel?

Comment: Is there a specific number of bits that are considered LSB? I mean, you could designate 7 bits per 8 bit color to be LSB but that doesn't seem right :) I could also see that differences of some colors are more distinct than others. Anyway, a good answer should probably address this particular issue. The calculation afterwards is just high school math I guess.

Comment: @user73481 It depends on the image format and the color space being used. For just common RGB with over 16 million of colors there are 8 + 8 + 8 pixels used for each pixel (for R, G and B), but that's excluding a possible (8 bit) Alpha channel that manages how opaque / transparent the pixel is. Of course, if you used *all* or almost all of that space then the image would look like (colorful) random noise, hence my initial joke.

Comment: It's actually a bit more complex than just the image size.  It really depends on the image and it's quality - see answer to [Steganography - How many bytes of information can you hide in a 1024×768
photo?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/47956/23115).

Comment: As a byte is just 8 bits and the answer could simply be divided by 7 bits, I guess I'd call that a dupe. And since I'm mod...